# Having Unity character problem in bones after importing from Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, 3dsmax

I have been following the following YouTube tutorial for character creation in blender. I am new to both Unity and Blender. I need this for my final year project and for my presentation.

I have some issues in character. I have downloaded the rig file from the description of this video but when I exported it into unity and changed its type to humanoid it shows me errors like "Required human bone "LeftFoot" not found" "Foot_L is not a child of Left Lower leg Transform 'Lower_Leg_L'".

When I manually assign left foot and several many errors when I manually try to do that looks like the parenting of bones is wrong but I am new so don't know anything, I need this character for my project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPEmonfLo94&t=20s

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out how to fix this.

The tutorial tells you to parent the 'foot bone' to the 'foot control' bone. This brakes the 'humanoid' bone chain in unity that expects that the foot is connected to the lower leg (which is not in this case).

Here is an image of my model. The 'Foot.L' bone is the selected one, and the Bone that is below to foot is the 'Foot Control.L' bone

[image: My Model;]

So, at the end of the rigging process explained on the tutorial (right before you duplicate the bones to make the right side) you will have to re-parent the 'Foot' Bone to the lower leg in order to export to unity.

**In edit mode:** Select the foot bone, then select the lower leg and hit CTRL+P / Connected

You might also parent the 'Foot Roll' bone to the 'Foot Control' bone.

**In edit mode:** Select the Foot Roll than Select the Foot Control and hit CTRL+P / Keep Offset.

Try the animation and check if it is ok, then, complete the rigging process by duplicating the bones just like the tutorial said and parent your model to the bones with automatic weights.

After that, export to unity to check if the humanoid feature works and game on!